# changing mouse cursor with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the script my Custom cursor is in the top left corner what means that something is wrong. I'm new to JavaScript so can anyone help me what I did wrong. Ignore that the Image doesn't work just look at the cursor and the interactables at the bottom. I tried to made that the cursor animates getting bigger if I hover over the interactable.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    // console.log(entry)
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add('show');
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove('show');
    }

  });
});

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));

const trailer = document.getElementById("trailer");

window.onmousemove = e => {
  const x = e.clientX - trailer.offsetWidth / 2;
  const y = e.clientY - trailer.offsetHeight / 2;
  const interactable = e.target.closest(".interactable");
  const interacting = interactable !== null;

  trailer.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;

  changeScale(interacting);
}

const changeScale = (interacting) => {

  const keyframes = {
    transform: `scale(${interacting ? 2 : 1})`
  }

  trailer.animate(keyframes, {
    duration: 800,
    fill: "forwards"
  });
}
```

```css
/* Main */

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  cursor: none;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px 20vw;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#trailer {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10000;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}

.interactable {}

body:hover>#trailer {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Social Media Icons */

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.wrapper .icon {
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.wrapper .icon span {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.wrapper .icon span i {
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.wrapper .icon .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 25px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.wrapper .icon:hover .tooltip {
  top: -70px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.icon .tooltip:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -6px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.wrapper .icon:hover span {
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .icon:hover span,
.wrapper .icon:hover .tooltip {
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.wrapper .discord:hover span,
.wrapper .discord:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .discord:hover .tooltip:before {
  background: #7289da;
}

.wrapper .github:hover span,
.wrapper .github:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .github:hover .tooltip:before {
  background: #333;
}

.wrapper .youtube:hover span,
.wrapper .youtube:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .youtube:hover .tooltip:before {
  background: #DE463B;
}


/* Animation Class */

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform: translateY(10%);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.changing-text {
  animation-name: fontChange;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


/* Fonts */

.playfair-display-font {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

.roboto-regular {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

.madimi-one-regular {
  font-family: "Madimi One", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}


/* Animations etc. */

@keyframes fontChange {
  0% {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  }
  10% {
    font-family: 'Courier New';
  }
  20% {
    font-family: 'Madimi One';
  }
  30% {
    font-family: 'Tahoma';
  }
  40% {
    font-family: 'Arial';
  }
  50% {
    font-family: 'Georgia';
  }
  60% {
    font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
  }
  70% {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  }
  80% {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  }
  90% {
    font-family: 'Brush Script MT';
  }
  100% {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
  }
}

@media(prefers-reduced-motion) {
  .hidden {
    transition: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="trailer"></div>

<section class="hidden">
  <h1 class="changing-text" style="font-size: 120px;">My Website</h1>
  <p>Look at these Animations!</p>
</section>
<section class="hidden">
  <h2 style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Coder &#60;/&#62;</h2>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0GQCkNK/ubuntu-term.png" alt="vim" height="650" style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgb(5, 5, 5);">
</section>
<section class="hidden">
  <h2>New</h2>
  <p>Amet dignissimos laudantium similique pariatur provident quod repellat id laborum recusandae modi. Ullam nulla fugit officia. Ratione minus, quos natus repudiandae ducimus aspernatur harum, possimus odio magni hic tempore incidunt!</p>
</section>
<section class="hidden">
  <h2>New</h2>
  <p>Delectus ratione animi doloribus sunt eius, unde reiciendis provident illum deleniti consequuntur quidem necessitatibus expedita quod enim voluptas corrupti quas repellat rem autem, pariatur maiores asperiores sint voluptatibus! Illum, voluptates.</p>
</section>
<section class="hidden">
  <h2 style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Find me on:</h2>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="https://discord.gg/KQjcgkZ3aJ" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">
      <div class="icon discord interactable">
        <div class="tooltip">
          Discord
        </div>
        <span><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://github.com/illy-dev" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">
      <div class="icon github interactable">
        <div class="tooltip">
          Github
        </div>
        <span><i class="fab fa-github"></i></span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">
      <div class="icon youtube interactable">
        <div class="tooltip">
          YouTube
        </div>
        <span><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Fonts -->

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Madimi+One&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Madimi+One&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400..900;1,400..900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: We also need your HTML and css code, you can make a snippet as @Barmar said to so we can reproduce the problem and see

Comment: If the code isn't producing the desired results, what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `windows.onmousemove` function.

Instead of calculating the cursor position based on the mouse coordinates and then setting the position, you should set the left and top styles of the cursor element based on the mouse coordinates. This ensures that the cursor stays at the correct position relative to the mouse.

Note: commented the log, it was annoying blocking visibility in the snippet

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        //console.log(entry)
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show');            
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show');
        }

    });
});

const hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));

const trailer = document.getElementById("trailer");

window.onmousemove = e => {
    const cursorWidth = trailer.offsetWidth;
    const cursorHeight = trailer.offsetHeight;
    const x = e.clientX;
    const y = e.clientY;
    const interactable = e.target.closest(".interactable");
    const interacting = interactable !== null;

    trailer.style.left = `${x - cursorWidth / 2}px`;
    trailer.style.top = `${y - cursorHeight / 2}px`;

    changeScale(interacting);
}

const changeScale = (interacting) => {

    const keyframes = {
        transform: `scale(${interacting ? 2 : 1})`
    }

    trailer.animate(keyframes, {
        duration: 800,
        fill: "forwards"
    });
}
```

```css
/* Main */
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    cursor: none;
}
  
section {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px 20vw;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#trailer {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;

    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 10000;

    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}

.interactable {
    
}

body:hover > #trailer {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Social Media Icons */
 .wrapper {
    display: inline-flex;
}
.wrapper .icon{
    margin: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
.wrapper .icon span {
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
.wrapper .icon span i{
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.wrapper .icon .tooltip{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #fff;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 25px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
.wrapper .icon:hover .tooltip{
    top: -70px;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.icon .tooltip:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -6px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
.wrapper .icon:hover span{
    color: #fff;
}
.wrapper .icon:hover span,
.wrapper .icon:hover .tooltip{
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.wrapper .discord:hover span,
.wrapper .discord:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .discord:hover .tooltip:before{
    background: #7289da;
}
.wrapper .github:hover span,
.wrapper .github:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .github:hover .tooltip:before{
    background: #333;
}
.wrapper .youtube:hover span,
.wrapper .youtube:hover .tooltip,
.wrapper .youtube:hover .tooltip:before{
    background: #DE463B;
}

/* Animation Class */
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translateY(10%);
    transition: all 1s;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.changing-text {
    animation-name: fontChange;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


/* Fonts */
.playfair-display-font {
    font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
    font-optical-sizing: auto;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
  }
.roboto-regular {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
  }

  .madimi-one-regular {
    font-family: "Madimi One", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
  }


/* Animations etc. */
@keyframes fontChange {
    0% {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    }
    10% {
        font-family: 'Courier New';
    }
    20% {
        font-family: 'Madimi One';
    }
    30% {
        font-family: 'Tahoma';
    }
    40% {
        font-family: 'Arial';
    }
    50% {
        font-family: 'Georgia';
    }
    60% {
        font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
    }
    70% {
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    }
    80% {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display';
    }
    90% {
        font-family: 'Brush Script MT';
    }
    100% {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
}

@media(prefers-reduced-motion) {
    .hidden {
        transition: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Madimi+One&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Madimi+One&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400..900;1,400..900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="trailer">

    </div>

    <section class="hidden">
        <h1 class="changing-text" style="font-size: 120px;">My Website</h1>
        <p>Look at these Animations!</p>
    </section>
    <section class="hidden">
        <h2 style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Coder &#60;/&#62;</h2>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0GQCkNK/ubuntu-term.png" alt="vim" height="650" style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgb(5, 5, 5);">
    </section>
    <section class="hidden">
        <h2>New</h2>
        <p>Amet dignissimos laudantium similique pariatur provident quod repellat id laborum recusandae modi. Ullam nulla fugit officia. Ratione minus, quos natus repudiandae ducimus aspernatur harum, possimus odio magni hic tempore incidunt!</p>
    </section>
    <section class="hidden">
        <h2>New</h2>
        <p>Delectus ratione animi doloribus sunt eius, unde reiciendis provident illum deleniti consequuntur quidem necessitatibus expedita quod enim voluptas corrupti quas repellat rem autem, pariatur maiores asperiores sint voluptatibus! Illum, voluptates.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="hidden">
        <h2 style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Find me on:</h2>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="https://discord.gg/KQjcgkZ3aJ" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;"><div class="icon discord interactable">
               <div class="tooltip">
                  Discord
               </div>
               <span><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></span>
            </div></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/illy-dev" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;"><div class="icon github interactable">
               <div class="tooltip">
                  Github
               </div>
               <span><i class="fab fa-github"></i></span>
            </div></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;"> <div class="icon youtube interactable">
               <div class="tooltip">
                  YouTube
               </div>
               <span><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></span>
            </div></a>
         </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```